# How to remove a REALM database

Tags: swift, realm

I would like to delete my REALM database when I logout from my iOS app, so I tried this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}
autoreleasepool {
    let realmURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
    let realmURLs = [
        realmURL,
        realmURL.URLByAppendingPathExtension("lock"),
        realmURL.URLByAppendingPathExtension("log_a"),
        realmURL.URLByAppendingPathExtension("log_b"),
        realmURL.URLByAppendingPathExtension("note")
    ]
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    for URL in realmURLs {
        do {
            try manager.removeItemAtURL(URL)
            Log.warning("Removed file at path: \(URL)")
        } catch {
            Log.error("Failed to remove file at path: \(URL)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then if I try to do this without restarting the app it crash:

```
do
{
    try realm.write() { realm.create(UserDB.self, value: currentUser) }
} catch {
    Log.error("Unable to record the user to DB")
//TODO: Handle this situation
}
```

And the crash:
`Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted.`

Update:
REALM files `log_a` and `log_b` aren't removed.
It only crash if I do a `realm.add` between reading the DB and removing it, else no problem.

Once deleted I will rewrite a new DB and the primary key will be the ID of the user, this is why it crash.  But how it can crash as my code should reset the DB?

Comment: Katsumi from Realm here. To isolate the problems, can you try without deleting files? To clear database, it's enough to call `realm.deleteAll()`. Deleting files isn't needed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, still crash the same way :/

Comment: Can you check whether the DB was cleared? Insert `print(ream.objects(User.self))` before `try realm.write() { realm.create(UserDB.self, value: currentUser) }` and tell me what printed?

Comment: Hi, The DB is cleared. `Results<UserDB> (

)
`.  Strange...